# Amazon EC2 Ubuntu missing update-rc.d?

Tags: ubuntu, amazon-ec2

I have a new Small Amazon Ubuntu server, using the standard AMI. I added a job to init.d, and I am trying to add a job to my startup using update-rc.d.  However, I get a command not found error for update-rc.d.  I thought this was part of the standard installation for Ubuntu, and I don't see any suggestions on how to install this.  Any thoughts?

Thanks!

Comment: This is same as http://serverfault.com/questions/345228/update-rc-d-on-amazon-linux/345231

Answer (score 3):

You might actually want to use `chkconfig`. For example, to enable memcached, you could do

```
sudo chkconfig --level 345 memcached on
```

After you reboot, memcached should be automatically started. This worked for me on the Amazon Linux AMI 2012.03.

Answer (score 2):

Are you admin? when I try its there.  Can you try to do do a:
`find / -name update-rc.d`  maybe its somewhere else or do you don't have permission.

Also what version of ubuntu are you using?

Comment: Yes - I am an admin.  I attempted to do a `sudo find ...` and found nothing.  Again, I am a bit surprised.  I am running a standard AMI on EC2 - here is the [link](https://aws.amazon.com/amazon-linux-ami/2012.03-release-notes/) to their most recent release that I am running - it says kernel version 3.2.12.  Thanks for checking.